# How to solve property isDialogOpen and setIsDialogOpen doesnt exist using context in react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i defined a context to set the isDialogOpen and setIsDialogOpen.

below is the snippet for context,

```
interface DialogCtxState {
    isDialogOpen: boolean;
    setIsDialogOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialDialogState: DialogCtxState = {
    isDialogOpen: false,
    setIsDialogOpen: () => {},
};

const DialogContext = React.createContext<DialogCtxState>(
    initialDialogState
);

export const DialogContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider
            value={{
                isDialogOpen,
                setIsDialogOpen,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

In the main component i wrap context provider like below,

```
function Main() {
    return (
        <DialogContext>
            <Child1/>
            <Child2/>
        </DialogContext/>
    );
}
```

In child1 component i access the isDialogOpen and setIsDialogOpen and set isDialogOpen in handle_click like below,

```
function Child1() {
   const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen} = React.useState(DialogContext); //i get error here
   const handle_click=()=> {
       setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
   }

   return (
       <isDialogOpen && <Upload/>}
   );
```

}

**what is the problem?**

I get the error in child1 component at this line

```
const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen} = React.useState(DialogContext);
```

Property isDialogOpen doesnt exist on type '[Context, Dispatch<SetStateAction<Context>>]'

Property setIsDialogOpen doesnt exist on type '[Context, Dispatch<SetStateAction<Context>>]'

I am not knowing how to solve this. could someone help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `useContext` instead of `useState`

```
const { isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen } = React.useContext(DialogContext);
```

Comment: No worries ;-)!